# Recommendation of different materials for 3D printing flexible parts

Tags: materials, plastic, 3d-printing

I am planning to 3D print this part from solidworks.

I am hoping to achieve a good level of flexibility with the clasps in this part.

- Thin circular arc in the **Top** drawing.

and

- Wider circular arc in the **Front** drawing.

The only flexible materials I have access to currently in the lab I work are nylon and polypropylene. I'm not sure which is a better, so I would like to get some recommendations. The flexibility I am looking to achieve is similar to that of the handle on a pen cap. I want the clasps to be able to flex enough to snap onto a circular tee without breaking, and if necessary be pulled open to take the part off again.

The thickness I am thinking of printing at is 0.1 mm thickness but I also need to be able to have the labels and tick marks be clear enough.

Ultimately I'm only interested in which material is best. Thanks.

[image: part]

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the interference/deflection to get good snap action? You should be able to do this with almost any plastic by adjusting the geometry.

Comment: The only geometry I can adjust is the angles, and I'll only have time for a limited number of prints. Because of covid requirements only one person can be in the lab, and only for a few hours. I am planning on doing multiple prints anyway but I'd like to reduce that number going in.

Comment: I would (highly) recommend printing this in two parts and bonding them together - or at least printing at 45degrees, so you're not relying on layer bonding on the stressed clips

Comment: @JonathanRSwift how would you recommend splitting the part?

Comment: This way - see how the layer lines are perpendicular to the bending stress? I would also add some features to help the joint (dowels, for example), but that's outside the scope of your question and my free time right now ;) https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoI0j.png

Comment: @JonathanRSwift fair enough :) . Looks like we have the same 3D printer too.

Comment: Well, I use Prusa Slicer with several non-Prusa printers! But good spot 

Comment: How do you intend on printing the R0.5" projection? It is a pretty large overhang.

Comment: I am planning on splitting the part in two @JonathanRSwift suggested. The overhang shouldn't be a problem since the "clock face" portion will be flat on the bed.